# Processing flat file with antlr4

Tags: antlr4, grammar

I need to process a flat text file and i was trying to generate a parser with antlr4. The format of the file is as follows:

1. The file can contain multiple records
2. Each line is one record
3. Each record has mutliple fields
4. The number of fields depends on the record type
5. The total length of each record is not fixed and depends on the number of individual fields
6. The record type is defined by the first 3 alphanumeric elements
7. Each field has a specific start position (column in record) and a number of elements

Sample file

```
ACF0000000101IAR
FAT0000000203IARGL9344KDKK
FAT0000000301IARGM
```

Sample Grammar

```
grammar Cat;

file : record+ ;

record: (file_header | cycle_header);

file_header : 'ACF' FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3;
cycle_header : 'FAT' FIELD1 FIELD2;

FIELD1 : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
FIELD2 : DIGIT DIGIT;
FIELD3 : ALPHANUM ALPHANUM ALPHANUM;

fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment ALPHANUM: [A-Za-z] | DIGIT | ' ';
fragment NEWLINE: '\n';
```

The problem i am facing with this grammar is that when i am inspecting the tree, FIELD2 in file_header rule is not matched but instead the FIELD3 is matched. Please keep in mind that the grammar is not complete for the cycle_header

[image: Tree]

My expectation was that since FIELD2 is preceding FIELD3 in the file_header rule this would match any two digit and the rest of the characters would be matched by FIELD3 but this is not the case as seen in the image.

So my questions are:

1. Is Antlr4 suitable for parsing such a file structure or some kind of parsing with regex would be more suitable
2. Why FIELD3 is matched before FIELD2, is there something i have misunderstood?

Comment: Antlr4 is probably not the optimal choice for this problem. The Antlr lexer is not really contextual, resulting in the problem you see; the lexer matches whichever lexical pattern has the longest match at the given input. You could use a scannerless approach, without lexical rules, but honestly you're probably better off just dividing the input line up with `substring()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is Antlr4 suitable for parsing such a file structure or some kind of parsing with regex would be more suitable

No, I agree with rici here. His comment really should've been an answer:

> > Antlr4 is probably not the optimal choice for this problem. The Antlr lexer is not really contextual, resulting in the problem you see; the lexer matches whichever lexical pattern has the longest match at the given input. You could use a scannerless approach, without lexical rules, but honestly you're probably better off just dividing the input line up with substring()

> 2. Why FIELD3 is matched before FIELD2, is there something i have misunderstood?

To expand on rici's comment: ANTLR's lexer is not "driven by the parser" (the lexer does not produce tokens depending on what the parser is trying to match). The lexer always creates tokens based on two simple rules:

1. try to match as much characters as possible
2. if two or more lexer rules match the same characters, let the rule that is defined first "win"

Because of rule 1, for input like `123` , a `FIELD3` is created before a `FIELD2`.

Comment: Having seen the token list generated i was expecting this would be the case. Thank you i will look for an alternative